# difference between "will have to" and "have to"

Tags: phrase-usage

> They can’t fix my computer. I’ll have to buy a new one.

The tense of the first sentence is the present. But in the following sentence "will have to" is used instead of "have to". I wonder why.

I want to know the difference between the following two sentences.

> They can’t fix my computer. I’ll have to buy a new one.
>
> They can’t fix my computer. I have to buy a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I’ll have to buy a new one." is in the future tense, and implies that you'll buy a new computer... but not at this instant. There's no rush. Maybe tomorrow, or next week.

"They can’t fix my computer. I have to buy a new one." is in the present tense. It's something you might say to the store clerk, while you are buying a new computer *in the present moment.*

However, the usage of the present tense is very generic. It doesn't strictly mean only the present moment. So, "I have to buy a new one" can be a general statement, without any indication of time-frame. You could be thinking "I have to buy a new one, but I will wait a few weeks."